# magento 2 swagger set in my staging server with my custom APIs

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I tried to access swagger using the below URL:

```
[domainname]/swagger
```

> curl -X POST 'https://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token' \
>        -H 'Content-Type:application/json' \
>        -d '{"username":"admin", "password":"admin123"}'

i get api_key and apply But still getting the below error

> 500 : {"message":"Internal Error. Details are available in Magento log file. Report ID: webapi-59fb1f6faeb4d"}

Comment: did you checked log file for reported error ?

Comment: no i dont get any log file. can you plz tell me folder where log creating.

Comment: In `var/log` folder

Comment: it not creating file